# Are there two $\pi$s?

Tags: trigonometry, constants

The mathematical constant $\pi$ occurs in the formula for the area of a circle, $A=\pi r^2$,
and in the formula for the circumference of a circle, $C= 2\pi r$. How does one prove that these constants are the same?

Comment: They are not the same. One is two times bigger :)

Comment: @O.L. Just beat me to it!

Comment: The one I've never understood is why the $m$ in the $F=ma$ law is the same as the $m$ in the $f = \frac{GmM}{r^2}$ law.  Why should susceptibility to gravitational attraction be the same as resistance to acceleration?

Comment: @MJD That's a deep [question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle). As I understand it, it's still an open question.

Comment: @MJD: That is precisely the question that Einstein answered so triumphantly with his General Theory of Relativity.

Comment: @MJD: That has also been tested by physicists. IIRC with a null experiment that would have showed the difference between the two, if one existed, when they differ by one part in $10^{12}$ or more.

Comment: There are "two $\pi$s" in $2\pi r$ and only one in $\pi r^2$.  But don't read this comment unless you want to.

Comment: I've posted an answer that ends with a "hard question": "In what contexts would this qualify as a 'proof'?".  But still I think you may find it of interest.

Answer (score 8):

The formula $C = 2\pi r$ is the *definition* of $\pi$.  That means when people ask what $\pi$ is, the answer is $\frac{C}{2r}$.

So the real question here is why is the area of a circle $\frac{1}{2}Cr$?  For an intuitive answer imagine cutting a circle into pizza slices and stacking then as in this picture:

$\hspace{5.5cm}$[image]

If your pizza slices are thin enough then that shape is almost a rectangle and we can get it's area by length times width.  The width is the radius and the length is half the circumference.  Thus $A = \frac{1}{2}Cr$.

Comment: See [this](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fc-2012-02) also.

Comment: @Jim Of course, that is one possible definition of $\pi$. There are others. In particular, this definition requires you to prove that it is independent of $\mathbb r$.

Comment: Or (again, for an intuitive answer), if you know the grade school formula $A = aP/2$ relating apethem and perimeter to area, simply consider a circle as a regular polygon of $\infty$ sides. I would think you could use the good old fashioned method of exhaustion to make this rigorous, too.

Comment: @Jim  This is a lovely INTUITIVE argument that goes back at least as far as Kepler (more historical detail would be welcome). It should be used in all elementary courses. But my question asks for a proof that the $\pi$ in the two formulas is the same.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews  An excellent point. Before one can define a constant one must show it is unique. See Tarksi's _Introduction to Logic_.

Comment: @FredRickey: This intuitive answer can be made rigorous by finding the dimensions of the smallest rectangle that contains, and the largest rectangle contained in, the "almost" rectangle in the picture.  These dimensions will depend on $n$, the number of cuts made to the circle.  Then use the squeeze theorem as $n \to \infty$ to get the result.

Comment: @JackM What was your elementary school??  I'm pretty sure I never learned the word 'apathem' in mine, much less that relation...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Actually neither did I, I was basing that on an something I saw in an American friend's high school homework once. Maybe I shouldn't have generalized that all americans learn that formula in class.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Archimedes argued that as far as area is concerned, a circle is equivalent to a triangle with the circumference as a base, and the radius as altitude on that base.

Comment: True. See _Measurement of the Circle_, proposition II. But this does not answer the question of why the two symbols $\pi$ in the formulas are the same.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see it is if you consider a circle with radius $r$ and another circle with radius $r+\Delta r$ (where $\Delta r\ll r$) around the same point, and consider the area between the two circles.

As with any shape, the area is proportional to the square of a typical length; the radius is such a typical length. That is, a circle of radius $r$ has the area $Cr^2$ with some constant $C$. Now the area in between the two circles  has the area $\Delta A = C(r+\Delta r)^2-Cr^2\approx 2Cr\,\Delta r$. That relation gets exact as $\Delta r\to 0$.

On the other hand, the distance between the two circles is constant, and therefore for sufficiently small $\Delta r$ you can "unroll" this shape into a rectangle (again, the error you make when doing this vanishes in the limit $\Delta r\to 0$). That rectangle has as one side the circumference, $2\pi r$,  and as the other side $\Delta r$. Since the area of a rectangle is the product of its side lengths, we get as area $\Delta A = 2\pi r\,\Delta r$.

Comparing the two equations, we get $2Cr\,\Delta r=2\pi r\,\Delta r$, that is, $C=\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I like to call the "boundary rule":
$$
\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}} [\text{rate of motion of boundary}]\times[\text{size of boundary}] \\[10pt]
& = [\text{rate of change of size of bounded region}]
\end{align}
$$

Apply this to a growing circle.  The rate of motion of the boundary is $\dfrac{dr}{dt}$.  The size of the boundary is $C$.  The rate of change of size of the bounded region is $\dfrac{dA}{dt}$.

Since $A$ is the area and $r$ is a distance, we must have
$$A=(\text{some constant}\cdot r^2).\tag{1}$$
Hence
$$
\begin{align}
C\frac{dr}{dt} & = \frac{dA}{dt} \text{ by the boundary rule} \\[6pt]
& = \frac{dA}{dr}\cdot\frac{dr}{dt}.
\end{align}
$$
Canceling, we get
$$
C = \frac{dA}{dr}.
$$
Applying $(1)$ and differentiating gives you equality of the two constants.

Now the hard question: In what contexts would this qualify as a "proof"?